# How to use resize in Squoosh CLI

Tags: node.js, terminal, command-line-interface, config, bulk

I want to make an program that import bulks images in Squoosh, but I don't know how to use **Squoosh/CLI** resize.

In **Squoosh/CLI** `--help` on `--resize` option I have: `--resize [config]`

And I don't know what I have to input in [].

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an object with key-value pairs right after `--resize` option.
You will get something like this:

```
--resize "{'enabled':true,'width':400,'method':'lanczos3','fitMethod':'stretch','premultiply':true,'linearRGB':true}"
```

I advise you to wrap the options object in double quotes while wrapping the key-value pairs in single quotes. It seems that some keys implicitly require single-quotes and will not work when wrapped around with double quotes. Personally, I've had this issue with 'width' and 'height' options enabled.

Comment: So where is this magic string documented?

Comment: The `fitMethod` option was not implemented in CLI. See here:  https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh/issues/921

Answer (score 0):

The `--resize` option only have `width`, `height`, `method`, `premultiply`, and `linearRGB`. All the available options can be found [here](https://github.com/doggy8088/squoosh/blob/42594277fd3d1f31b60103eb05cc8df62a82fb86/libsquoosh/src/codecs.ts#L32C32-L38C2).

Here is the definition for `--resize`:

```js
{
  width: number;
  height: number;
  method: 'triangle' | 'catrom' | 'mitchell' | 'lanczos3';
  premultiply: true;
  linearRGB: true;
}
```

For example:

```
--resize "{'enabled':true,'width':400,'method':'lanczos3','fitMethod':'stretch','premultiply':true,'linearRGB':true}"
```

I also made a full documentation for Squoosh CLI here: https://hub.docker.com/r/willh/squoosh-cli

If you are using Windows, I would recommend you to use Docker container to run Squoosh CLI. You can see my implementation here: [willh/squoosh-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/willh/squoosh-cli)